# How to read image path using jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, cycle

Basically, I wish to change the slash design as shown below (red box). So I decided to change it to image instead of code.

[image]  change to  [image]

May I know how to change the slash `'/'` to image path --> `<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/icons/slash.jpg" />` by using the following code?

```
 $('#counter').text((options.currSlide + 1) + '/' + (options.slideCount));
```

This is my wrong answer

```
$('#counter').text((options.currSlide + 1) + '<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/icons/slash.jpg" />' + (options.slideCount));
```

Hope some of you could provide me with some advice.

Click here, if you need the completed code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Dhqdc/2/)

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, can you describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I have amended my question, is it clear enough? Let me know which part you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check out the following link  - http://jsfiddle.net/Dhqdc/104/

Change in Jquery from

```
$('#counter').text((options.currSlide + 1) + '/' + (options.slideCount));
```

to

```
$('#counter').html((options.currSlide + 1) + $(this).html() + (options.slideCount));
```

Change in Css done (you can change it depending on your needs)

```
.image-slides img{padding:10px;background-color:green}
```

to

```
.image-slides,#counter img{padding:1px;background-color:green}
```

Change in html (change according to your need)

```
<div class="image-slides">
```

to

```
<div class="image-slides" style="display:none">
```

I adjusted some css & html to show the demo better , yet the jquery change is one that you are looking for.
I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Cool! But can I change to another image by reading another class? Like this --> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eelyn/76kmr0sn/1/), but this is wrong code.